# Do While Loop and ExpectedConditions - Possible to use together?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Do While Loop and ExpectedConditions - Possible to use together?

1. Iam getting the odd unable to locate element / timeout exception with the method listed below.

**2. Is it possible to add a while loop so the method can check and execute more than once?**

```
    public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
        System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the WebElement: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on WebElement, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        Assert.assertFalse(true, "Unable to wait and click on the WebElement, using locator: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats possible. Something like this:

```
    boolean clicked = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(!clicked && attempts < 5) {
    try {
            this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
            System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the WebElement: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
            clicked = true;
     } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on WebElement, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Assert.assertFalse(true, "Unable to wait and click on the WebElement, using locator: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
        }
         attempts++;
    }
```

It might be a good idea to add a max attempts to your while loop too, so you dont get caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: would i add another while look inside for the max attempts? thanks allot for your help

Comment: no, you could incorporate it into the existing one. ill make an edit